# Photoshop CS5 insane slow on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, performance, adobe-cs5

I've bought a powerful machine, Intel I7 720Q with 8 GB RAM and 7200 RPM HDD and Radeon 5870 with 1GB VRAM, 
and after installing the new **Adobe Master collection CS5** I found out, 
that both `Photoshop` versions `x86` and `x64` are very slow (I have a legal copy!)

E.g. when I open a **3MB** file and I'm trying to *move it with the hand*, or *scroll*, it is going very slowly, laggy, 10x slower than on my 4 years old machine with CS2 !

Do I have to enable any kind of acceleration or something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you finally find the answer to your question?

Comment: Why would anybody buy the Master Collection?

Comment: @jason404:  The master collection is heavily reduced in price for students at our university.  75% discount or something so I can see why people here might buy it.

Comment: Strange, I'm running a much older machine and Photoshop CS5 x64 runs perfectly fine. I'd make sure your Graphics Card's drivers are up to date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow, seems CS5 is slow for a lot of people!!

I've found this KB from Adobe regarding OpenGL and GPU acceleration:

[GPU and OpenGL support | Photoshop CS4, CS5](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html)

I'm pretty sure it could help you because you do have a powerful computer and this shouldn't cause CS5 to act like this.

Then, read this, for some other tweaks:

[Optimize Photoshop performance | CS4, CS5 | Windows 7, Vista, XP](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404439.html)

If you don't have a professional graphics card try this:

Preferences > Performance > GPU > OpenGL advanced settings > basic mode

Answer (score 3):

I disable "enable openGL drawin" and restarted PS and... WOW - now everything works soo fast :)

Comment: is this 32 or 64bit version?

Comment: Another happy camper. Unchecked
Edit>Preferences>Performance>Enable openGL drawin>ok
Now runs great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just read that many people have problems like me. Especially with scrolling..
This is a patch for it.. Didn't try it yet though

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4733

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some problem or misconfiguration with the hardware aceleration. I use CS5 in a Acer Aspire netbook with 4Gb ram, Intel Core Duo t5800 (very average) and a Intel Mobile 4 VideoCard, and it works reasonably well.

In Preferences-> Performance, I´ll try first with the Memory Usage option and the scratch disk, it's better to use a disk where the Photoshop is not installed, if you have 2 or more.

And of course enabling the OpenGL aceleration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, everything slow on a  decent laptop. Instead of disabling "openGL drawin" I set it basic under advanced settings, and voila. (64bit)